# Why cant I input data into the <input type="text"> inside InfoWindow (Google Map)

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have this code below to input text in HTML `input type="text"`, so weird because I cant input data in the second `input type="text"`. Please see the image below.

**NOTE:**  The html code below was loaded by a `WebView`.

**Code:**

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
   info.setContent("<p style='color:black; font-size:15px;'>Loading...<p>");
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
       var address = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
       if(address.results){
           addresstext = address.results[0].formatted_address;
           var loctitle = "<p style='font-size:13px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px'>Location</p>";
           var loctext = "<p style='font-size:13px;'>"+addresstext+"<p>";
           var infotitle = "<p style='font-size:13px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px'>Additional Info</p>";
           var label1 = "<label style='font-size:13px;'>Blk No / Lot No : <label>";
           var label2 = "<br><label style='font-size:13px;'>Building Name : <label>";
           var blkno = "<input type='text'></input>";
           var bldng = "<input type='text'></input>";
           info.setContent(loctitle + loctext + infotitle + label1 + blkno + label2 + bldng);
           info.open(map,marker);
        }
     }
  }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+location+"&sensor=true",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

**Image:**

[image]

**Everytime I made an input to that textfield, it will just go back to the first textfield!**

Comment: try to close label tags with `</label>` (note slash) and give your input tags an id: `<input id='blkno' />`, `<input id='buildingname' />`

Answer (score 0):

1. You miss slash in closing tag `</label>`, try next:

   ```
   var label1 = "<label style='font-size:13px;'>Blk No / Lot No : </label>";
   var label2 = "<br><label style='font-size:13px;'>Building Name : </label>";
   ```
2. Give your input tags an id:

   ```
   <input id='blkno' />
   <input id='buildingname' />
   ```